# jQuery : Target 3rd element to follow (not child)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a div `<div class="other_value">` which has a `display:none` (class `other_value` in html snippet)  and i would like to show it when i select "other" in my html select.

I can do it if the hidden div is just next to the select :

```
$('.select-additional-infos').on('change', function () {

    if ($(this).val() === "autre") {
        $(this).next().show();
    } else {
        $(this).next().hide();
    }
});
```

But, i add an `<input type="hidden">` between the `<select>` and this hidden div `<div class="other_value">` and i can not target this div (`<div class="other_value">`).

Here is what i’ve tried :

```
$(this).next().find('.other_value').show();

$(this).closest('div').find('.other_value').show();
```

Here is the HTML

```
<select class="form-control select-additional-infos" id="infos_21" name="60_infos_21">
    <option value="non renseigné" selected="selected">non renseigné</option>
    <option value="général">1</option>
    <option value="agricole">2</option>
    <option value="non salarié">3</option>
    <option value="autre">other</option>
</select>

<input type="hidden" value="label : " name="xxx">

<div class="other_value">
    <!— some html —>
</div>
```

SNIPPET

```js
$(this).next().find('.other_value').show();
```

```css
.other_value {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="form-control select-additional-infos" id="infos_21" name="60_infos_21">
    <option value="non renseigné" selected="selected">non renseigné</option>
    <option value="général">1</option>
    <option value="agricole">2</option>
    <option value="non salarié">3</option>
    <option value="autre">other</option>
</select>

<input type="hidden" value="label : " name="xxx">

<div class="other_value">
    <!— some html —>
</div>

<select class="form-control select-additional-infos" id="infos_22" name="60_infos_22">
    <option value="non renseigné" selected="selected">non renseigné</option>
    <option value="général">1</option>
    <option value="agricole">2</option>
    <option value="non salarié">3</option>
    <option value="autre">other</option>
</select>

<input type="hidden" value="label : " name="xxx">

<div class="other_value">
    <!— some html —>
</div>
```

EDIT :

I forgot to say that i have multiple `select` in the same page (i build the form dynamically from datas stored in database) so i don’t know the select name. I need to use something with `$this` i think.

Comment: simply using **$(this).next().next().show()** and  **$(this).next().next().hide()** will work

Comment: @Mak OMG no... A single change in HTML should not break JS functionality.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan : I thought this HTML template is the fixed one and div was always going to be after the hidden input and select....If that not the case then this will not work.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan For now, it is fixed but of course it could be built differently so i prefer a solution that will work in any case (assuming that the `input` will be close to each `select`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `nextAll()` and then select first with `.other_value` class. Here is demo with multiple selects [**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/Lg0wyt9u/2417/)

```js
$('select').change(function() {
  $(this).nextAll('.other_value:first').toggle($(this).val() == 'autre')
})
```

```css
.other_value {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="form-control select-additional-infos" id="infos_21" name="60_infos_21">
    <option value="non renseigné" selected="selected">non renseigné</option>
    <option value="général">1</option>
    <option value="agricole">2</option>
    <option value="non salarié">3</option>
    <option value="autre">other</option>
</select>

<input type="hidden" value="label : " name="xxx">
<div class="other_value" >
   Other 1
</div>
<div class="other_value" >
   Other 2
</div>
```

Comment: @Sébastien Gicquel  Take a look at update, i think its a better solution.

Comment: It works and it seems to be more robust (works even if i change the `html` (assuming that the `input` will be close to each `select`).

Answer (score 0):

`.show()` and `.hide()` operate over an element CSS `display` property, not over `type=""` property. Therefore:

```js
$('.select-additional-infos').on('change', function () {

  $("[name='xxx']").prop("type", this.value==="autre" ? "text" : "hidden");

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select class="form-control select-additional-infos" id="infos_21" name="60_infos_21">
    <option value="non renseigné" selected="selected">non renseigné</option>
    <option value="général">1</option>
    <option value="agricole">2</option>
    <option value="non salarié">3</option>
    <option value="autre">other</option>
</select>

<input type="hidden" value="label : " name="xxx">

<div class="other_value">
    <!— some html —>
</div>
```

If you really want to operate over it's `display` state than:

- Create a css `.hidden` and assign it to your input element
- Toggle that `hidden` class using JS depending on the `select` value

```js
$('.select-additional-infos').on('change', function () {

  $("[name='xxx']").toggleClass("hidden", this.value!=="autre");

});
```

```css
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select class="form-control select-additional-infos" id="infos_21" name="60_infos_21">
    <option value="non renseigné" selected="selected">non renseigné</option>
    <option value="général">1</option>
    <option value="agricole">2</option>
    <option value="non salarié">3</option>
    <option value="autre">other</option>
</select>

<!-- NOTICE .hidden -->
<input type="text" class="hidden" value="label : " name="xxx">

<div class="other_value">
    <!— some html —>
</div>
```

Comment: I forgot to say that i have multiple select in the same page (i build the form dynamically from datas stored in database) so i don’t know the select name. I need to use something with `$this` i think.

Comment: @SébastienGicquel well, than use `$(this).next("input")` - or rather `$(this).closest(".someCommonParent").find("input")` (to not depend on being *next* - and stuff...)

Comment: I've tried but neither of the two solutions works in my case but i'll try to adapt to my code.(`$(this).next("input")` or `$(this).closest(".someCommonParent").find("input")`